# Smalles subfield

Tags: analysis, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $L\subset K$. $L$ is a subfield of $K$ if:

$0,1\in L$

$x+y,x*y \in L$ if $x,y \in L$ and

$x^{-1} \in L$ if $x \in L^{\times}=L$ without ${0}$

a) Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):=(a+b * \sqrt{2} | a,b \in \mathbb{Q})\subset \mathbb{R}$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$

Proving that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a field works:
$x+y = (a+b * \sqrt{2}) + (c+d * \sqrt{2}). $
same for multiplication.

The inverse is $(a+b * \sqrt{2}) * (c+d * \sqrt{2} = (2bd+ac)+(ad+bc)\sqrt{2}=1$ with $a,c = 0$ and $b,d = 0.5$

and so on...

How do I formally prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the smallest subfield?

Task b) is: Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a ordered field with the from $\mathbb{R}$ induced operations "+" and "*" and "$\leq$" but without being  totally ordered.

No idea so far how to prove b)

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that if $L$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ it must contain all numbers from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as it must be closed under $\ast$ and $+$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq L$ for all such subfields, and as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ *is* itself a subfield, it's the minimal one.

It's better to write $x+y = (a+b\sqrt{2}) + (c + d\sqrt{2}) = (a+c) + (b+d)\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$

and for the inverse $$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2 -2b^2} = \frac{a}{a^2-2b^2} + \frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$$

etc.

I think $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ *is* a totally ordered field. Why wouldn't it be? All axioms get inherited, as does the totallness of the order.

Of course $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ is an ordered field, maybe that was the question originally?